# The writing is on the wall for these hieroglyphics

Tags: cipher, language

My mother, turning 80 this month, is convinced that anyone born into [Generation Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_Z) will not be able to decipher the following.

[image: Picture]

This is an ancient form of communication called "[Cursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursive)" *[kur-siv]*, which is soon to be as extinct as the Latin language and the Mullet hairstyle.

> Is there anyone out there who can decrypt it?

- ***50*** imaginary bonus points for correct answers from PSE members born after 1998
- ***10*** additional imaginary bonus points for those who correctly transcribe the answer [image: in cursive, not with computer font.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cipher is

> a Caesar shift of 7: hence "of" becomes "vm", "the" becomes "aol", etc. (Notice how common "vm" and "aol" are in the ciphertext.

The cursive ciphertext is

> Vul wyljvjpvbz Qlhu Svbpzl "Zjvba" Mpujo dhz mhy holhk vm hss vm aol vaoly mpyza nyhklyz ha aol Thfjvti zjovvs pu Ohywly Sll'z uvcls Av Rpss h Tvjrpunipyk. Zol jvbsk hsylhkf ylhk huk dypal jbyzpcl, lclu iba oly alhjoly, Tpzz Jhyvspul, zovdlk uv hwwyljphapvu mvy aolzl zrpssz.

The deciphered plaintext is

> One precocious Jean Louise "Scout" Finch was far ahead of all of the other first graders at the Maycomb school in Harper Lee's novel To Kill a Mockingbird. She could already read and write cursive, even but her teacher, Miss Caroline, showed no appreciation for these skills.

And how's THIS for illegible?

> [image: plaintext]

Comment: Are you gen Z though?

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that you get none of the highly coveted imaginary bonus points...

Comment: @Chowzen I haven't even heard the phrase "generation Z" before - something the kids these days go on about? I did illegify the plaintext for you though :-P

Comment: You haven't heard the phrase "generation Z," yet you're completely comfortable using "illegify" in everyday conversation? (－‸ლ)

Answer (score 6):

I would've figured it out, but Rand beat me to it by a long shot. Anyhow, to make your mother happy, (and also to get 10 imaginary bonus points), here is the cursive, handwritten:

> [image]

Comment: For sake of privacy, I wont reveal my age, but lets just say I'm born AFTER 2000, of course, still within the SE age limit

Comment: [point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point][point]

Comment: +1 for handwriting! I also fixed the spoilertagging for you :-)

Comment: @Chowzen Flagged as spam :-P

Comment: 13 imaginary points retroactively deducted from North for writing ***outside the red margins!!!*** You even hit a three-ring binder pothole!

Comment: Nooooooooo Gosh darn it